# Is it possible to deploy my DialogFlow agent to multiple slack workspaces?

Tags: dialogflow-es, slack, slack-api

Is it possible to deploy my DialogFlow agent to multiple slack workspaces as it seems like there is a one on one connection between the slack API and Dialogflow agent?